# How does React framework work under-the-hood?

Tags: reactjs

Simply put, how does the index.js get loaded? I don't see this referenced anywhere.

I am guessing the App.js is referenced from the manifest.json.

Comment: That you omitted the reference to the article and CRA made the question less intelligible. The question about index.js which didn't present in original post is applicable to CRA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`create-react-app` is just a generator for a project that uses `react-scripts`, which is preconfigured Webpack setup.

`App.js` is used in `index.js`, and this can be tracked in project source files. index.js is entry point for Webpack bunhdle. Bundled application is loaded with `<script>` in index HTML page. The project contains only [a template for HTML page](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/public/index.html) which doesn't contain this `<script>`, the tag is added dynamically. Actual HTML page is [generated from this template at build time with Webpack plugins](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/773d10398675ecaa60f3e3d5e0cc731c3de4a918/packages/react-scripts/config/webpack.config.js#L521-L557).

Webpack setup can be examined by checking `react-scripts` source code or [ejecting the project](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md).